# C generic type as function argument input

Tags: c, function, types, struct, arguments

So I have two different structs in which all the properties that I will be accessing will be the same. and I also have a function, who's argument, i want to be able to accept either of the two. Example:

```
typedef struct{
    int whatnot = 14;
    int thing[11];
} TH_CONFIG;

typedef struct{
    int whatnot = 3;
    int thing[5];
} TH_CONFIG_2;

*_CONFIG var;

void fun(*_CONFIG input)
{
    input.whatnot = 5;
}

int main(){
    fun(var);
}
```

I may have an inkling that I should use void as the type from that I could typecast or something?, but my searching has only yielded things about function pointers, templates, and C#.

EDIT: *_CONFIG is not meant to be syntactically correct, its signifying that I don't know what to do there, but its supposed to be the _CONFIG type

Comment: `void fun(*_CONFIG input)` - that's a syntax error.

Comment: You might want to read about [unions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union).

Comment: Those two structures are not compatible; the `int whatnot = 3;` notation is not valid C; the `*_CONFIG var;` is not valid C; the `void fun(*_CONFIG input)` is not valid C.  Generally, a function should only work on one type; otherwise, it lacks functional cohesiveness.  If you must, you can pass the values via `void *` and something else that identifies the type the `void *` points at.  Or you can use a `union` of the types.  You can even use the `.whatnot` member to identify which type you're dealing with if all the types in the union have that member present and it contains a separate value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions.

1. Just use an array of length 11 for both of them.  Did you really run out of those last 6 bytes on your OS?
2. Make it a dynamic array.
3. Just write in assembly, you clearly don't care about C's higher-level-ness.
4. Use a language like C++ that supports templates or polymorphism.
5. Just pass in the arguments of the `struct` you care about.

   void fun(int* whatnot) {
       *whatnot = 5;
   }

   int main() {
       fun(&myStruct.whatnot);
       return 0;
   }
6. Factor into a quasi-OO design.

   struct {
       int whatnot;
   } typedef Common;

   struct TH_CONFIG_1 {
       Common common;
       int thing[11];
   };

   struct TH_CONFIG_2 {
       Common common;
       int thing[5];
   }

But if you insist...

```
void fun(void* input) {
    ( (int)(*input) ) = 5;
}
```

or...

```
void fun(void* input) {
    ( (TH_CONFIG*) input)->whatnot = 5; // may have been a TH_CONFIG_2, but who cares?
}
```

Note:  this would not pass code review at any C shop.

Comment: 1. yes
2. cant
3. no
4. cant
5. there are too many arguments, but thanks for the first non-condescending suggestion
6. wouldn't really solve the problem, i think? i would still have 2 different structs not being input into a single function. i could be wrong though.
onward: thank you, for your last suggestion, this code isnt being reviewed.

Comment: @DanielCardin to be fair 3 was the only condescending suggestion.  I'm surprised you're this memory-tight and there are 99-to-1 SO questions for people who think they are memory or CPU bound but really are just premature optimizing so I *have* to be diligent on this. You will get better support on SO if you more thoroughly answer "What have you tried?" i.e. explain why 1, 2, and 4 are off the table.  6 you would use in conjunction with 5 to reduce the "too many args" problem.  But if you're really going with 7 then you're just hacking yourself out of C and writing impossible to maintain code.

Comment: @DanielCardin Basically if I were in your position and am postulating that 1, 2 and 4 are not acceptable, I would call 5 a correct tradeoff.  Too many arguments is preferable to bypassing typing.

Comment: Once I see condescension, it bleeds into everything else. 
I don't have to go with 7, but it seemed like the easiest/best solution  compared to having a ridiculous number of arguments. I can see how 6 would aggregate all the non-array args, but how would that solve the differing TH_CONFIG_1 and _2?

Comment: @DanielCardin 6 doesn't solve the differing types alone.  It solves the unmanaged arguments problem of 5.  I absolutely would prefer unmanaged args to the solution in 7...  which will break at runtime if someone else so much as decides to reorder your args by alphabetical, implement 6, etc.  If you do not understand the dangers of that method you should not use it.

Comment: @DanielCardin there's nothing wrong with many arguments.  It's not going to affect your performance or bottom line.  It just looks ugly.  But unsafe casting looks ugly *and* causes runtime bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any pointer type and cast it.

If all the properties you're accessing are the same, I'm guessing one's an extension of the other (since the properties need to have the same offset from the beginning of the struct). In that case you may want to use this pattern:

```
struct base {
  int foo;
  char **strings;
};

struct extended {
  struct base super;
  double other_stuff;
};
```

Since `super` is at the start of `struct extended`, you can cast a `struct extended *` to `struct base *` without problems. Of course, you could do that by repeating the same fields in the beginning of `struct extended` instead, but then you're repeating yourself.

Comment: they're really the same structs, but with different values and lengths of arrays that I can't really malloc, and need to be hardcoded.